# null reference exception string array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist, nullreferenceexception

im getting this error of null reference

```
private int Cont;
private List<string> myStrings;
private ArrayList str;
private string[] strs;

     myclass()
     {
        Cont = 0;
        myStrings = new List<string>();
        str = new ArrayList();
        strs =new string[27];   
        for(int i = 0; i < 27;i++)
        {
            strs[i] = "";
        }
     }

    public void AddTexture(string name)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Count "+Cont);
        Console.WriteLine("ive got the texture "+name);
        myStrings.Add(name);
        //strs[Cont] = name;
        //str.Add(name);
        Cont++;
     }
```

as you see i've tried with list,arraylist and arrays and none of them work when i try to add the first value i get that error i have seriously no idea whats happening i am getting a string in name,and Cont = 0 in the 1st write line

any idea what im doing wrong? thank you
the error is whenever im trying to fill the array,arraylist or the list
in the function AddTexture after the 2 console.writeline i've commented those 2 lines but thats because those are the ways i tried to use the array,arraylist and the list

Comment: whenever i try to fill the array or arraylist or list

Comment: in the function addtexture after the console.writelines

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Use the debugger.  Did you call that constructor?

Comment: sry to be rude but a list is not supposed to give me that error neither an arraylist and yes the constructor is called

Comment: This would happen if the field is null.  Did you check in the debugger and make sure that it is not null?

Comment: the field? meaning the string im getting in the function or the list,arraylist,array? if its the string in the function it is not null im even printing it

Comment: also im initializing all of those variables in the constructor and even filling my array with ""

Comment: yes it should be correct... but im stil getting that error

Comment: When and where is AddTexture being called?

Comment: the only thing missing in that class is the class name lol public class myclass{

Comment: well addtexture is called when the application is starting first,loading a txt file,parse it with json,and then i call that function

Comment: the error is in AddTexture or the constructor?

Comment: Is AddTexture being called before the constructor?

Comment: Wow that was it i was initializing it in 3 different objects and 1 of them was being called before the constructor thank you very much if you post it as answer i will make give you points

Comment: @Luke Wyatt AddTexture is not static method.it can not called before the class is not declared.

Comment: well it was being called before somehow... i just did a console.writeline at the constructor and it was after

Comment: @Habib - It was declared but not initialize I'm assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good, I was a little late though:

To sum it up, the issue was due to the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

So no-one else reads 30 comments to find out its already solved:

*When and where is AddTexture being called?

Is AddTexture being called before the constructor? – Luke Wyatt*

> Wow that was it i was initializing it in 3 different objects and 1 of
>   them was being called before the constructor thank you very much if
>   you post it as answer i will make give you points

Comment: well this was suppossed to be luke's answer but w/e thank you for posting i was waiting for him tho